# Apply css style to all primeng dialogs in my angular app

Tags: javascript, css, angular, styles, primeng

I am using prime ng dialog all over my angular application. I can change each specific dialog style by using ng-deep. For eg I have contact us page for which I have these files:

```
contact.html
contact.component.ts
contact.css
```

So I place the below css in contact.css and it changes the contact us dialog title bar color.

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{
    background-color: red
}
```

I want to do this for all the dialogs in my application, how can I do this? I placed the same css in style.css file in src folder and it didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you're using just a good 'ol default structure of angular, just put it at the highest point in the order of inception. Like the `app.component.css` or event just `<style>.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{  background-color: red}</style>` right in the index.html, there's lots of techniques, some considered cleaner than others, but would help to know just how default your setup is to give a best practice.

Comment: Looks like placing it in app.component.css does the trick. Can you put your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Did a lot of search online and couldn't find anything that mentioned this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So angular components by default employ a very handy strategy of [Style Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) which makes it so that styles don't bleed out into other components and cause unwanted effects.

You can utilize `ng-deep` like you have to allow styles defined within it to be inherited by child components of where it's specified.

However for things to be globally inherited you'll want to define them highest up in the order of inception so those styles **cascade** down to selectors below. In a default angular application that's not using SCSS or another pre-processor one of the easiest ways to do this is to add them to one of the first files initialized that hosts the child components such as `index.html` or `app.component` to allow components initialized afterwards to inherit them when they're rendered.

Hope this helps, cheers!